# Method with "params" being called, even though there's a more specific one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, parameters, overloading, overload-resolution

I have two overloaded methods, one with params and one without. If I call that method without specifying any params, it hits the one with params all the same.

Take the following example:

```c#
public abstract class A<T>
{
  public virtual T Get(int idEntity)
  {
    return this.DefaultRepository.Get(idEntity);
  }
}

public class B<T> : A<T>
{
  public override T Get(int idEntity)
  {
    this.DoSomeValidation();
    var t = this.GetTheEntity();
    return t;
  }

  public T Get(int idEntity, params sbyte[] AccessModifiers)
  {
    this.DoOtherValidations(AccessModifiers);
    var t = this.GetTheEntity();
    return t;
  }
}
```

If I do this in another class:

```c#
public class SomeClass
{
  public void SomeMethod(int idT)
  {
    var x = new B();
    var t = B.Get(idT);
  }
}
```

Then the method `public T Get(int idEntity, params sbyte[] AccessModifiers)` is called, instead of `public override T Get(int idEntity)`. I was expecting the latter to be called, it being more specific than the former, since I didn't specify any "params". Why is that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Your `class B : A` requires a type argument for `A<T>`. If you have a separate non-generic class `A`  then that might be part of the problem.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is "because it's a "first-class" member of type `B`" and the overridden one is not, but I'd have to read through the specification to verify..

Comment: @RonBeyer When I run it in LinqPad with `B<T>` as `this`, then it calls the `params` version - when I change it to a virtual call from `A<T>` as `this` then it calls the non-params method - so you're right.

Comment: So in conclusion, an empty params array is considered more specific than a virtual method without params.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The issue was, the params version is called, you confirm the issue. We look for the specification explaining the behaviour.

Comment: Obviously both methods match that signature, so the one from `B` is chosen rather than the base method. You can use `((A<T>)(new B<T>())).Get(1);` to call the other method. if it wasn't an `override` then the `params`less one would be chosen first.

Comment: I get the reason now, thanks to @Bizhan, though it's kinda confusing. In our case, we own both assemblies, so we can look at the code, but I imagine it would be a huge headache if it happenned with an external assembly.